# Cannot connect to bluetooth speaker logitech Boombox

Tags: sound, bluetooth, speakers, logitech

i looked and couldn't find an answer to my problem. I am trying to connect to my Logitech Boombox via bluetooth. It recognizes the device, but once it pairs it claims "failed authentication".

Thx, 
Sebas

Comment: check it once http://nex.scrapping.cc/articles/linux-bluez-a2dp-alsa.html

Comment: I have the same issue, only Ubuntu does not even recognise the speakers in the first place. Connecting them to my phone is not a problem. I tried installing Blueman Bluetooth Manager and but it didn't find my speakers either.

Comment: On Debian Wheezy (I do not have an Ubuntu install handy to test), I successfully paired the device with my Lenovo ThinkPad x201, but it did not appear as a device in Sound Settings until I ran the following: sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth && 
pacmd load-module module-bluetooth-discover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem running Ubuntu 13.04, with a Logithech Boombox UE. In my case the solution was to edit the `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` file.

Under section `[General]` add:

```
Disable=Socket
Enable=Source
```

This should get the connection working. However, the sound is faltering and I had to add further modifications to the file.

In the same section add:

```
SCORouting=PCM
AutoConnect=true
```

Under section `[Headset]` add:

```
HFP=false
SBCSources=1
MPEG12Sources=0
```

This solved the problem for me.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered exactly the same problem with Bluetooth 4.99 - I've Googled my eyeballs out on this, posted for help on numerous forums, tried all possible tips & tweaks.  Nothing.  Logitech support are useless on this.

Somebody, somewhere, must have some ideas on how to fix this!

Comment: On Debian Wheezy (I do not have an Ubuntu install handy to test), I successfully paired the device with my Lenovo ThinkPad x201, but it did not appear as a device in Sound Settings until I ran the following: sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth && pacmd load-module module-bluetooth-discover

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 Boombox didn't connect any more. Installing pipewire-pulse solved the problem.