# XUbuntu 14.04 - Logitech Mini Boombox Speaker Fails to Connect/stream sound over bluetooth

Tags: sound, xubuntu, bluetooth

Installed Xubuntu 14.04 today and again unable to get Logitech Mini Boombox to connect via bluetooth in Linux. I have had the same problem in different versions of Linux distro's and and have tried some of the fixes suggested on the internet and this forum but each time I am unsuccessful.
I am able to get the device added and it seems to pair.
It connects to headset service but the sound still comes out of my PC speakers.
A2DP Sink (send audio) Audio sink - stream setup fails as follows.
Error message: Device added successfully but failed to connect.
Error message: Connection Failed: Stream setup failed.

Would appreciate any help to sort this out.

Thanks

Comment: On Debian Wheezy (I do not have an Xubuntu install handy to test), I successfully paired the device with my Lenovo ThinkPad x201, but it did not appear as a device in GNOME Sound Settings until I ran the following: sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth && pacmd load-module module-bluetooth-discover

Answer (score 0):

There is already a thread that probably answers this:
[Cannot connect to bluetooth speaker logitech Boombox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252794/cannot-connect-to-bluetooth-speaker-logitech-boombox)

I too had faced the same issue and implemented the solution in the link I shared. However, the problem persisted. Strangely, it went away when I did the same thing (add my logitech miniboom box bluetooth device) using an alternative way (not through the task bar's bluetooth icon). I went through the System Settings dialog, selected Bluetooth (Hardware section) and tried to add the device. It worked!

So my feeling is that you have to implement the instructions in the link (Damian Nadelas's answer) and then add the device using System Settings.

Comment: Sorry to say that the above solution only worked sporadically. But when I upgraded my 32-bit OS to 64-bit, the problem disappeared. I am now able to connect my Mini Boombox without problems.